# Database synchronization alternatives

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, data-synchronization

We currently have a centralized database (MySQL) where some data is loaded. Then we have a lot of Android devices with a copy of this database (SQLite). Our dynamic is to deliver every change/event made in the server database to our clients, Android devices. And of course capture all the transactions made by the clients and take them to the server in a consistent way.

Our current solution is an adaptation of SymmetricDS. We would like to explore some other solutions for this synchronization task.

We are looking for a  synchronization method that provides the following features:
The ability to work offline mode (Our android clients won’t have access to the network all the time).
General purpose (an easy way to include some new model/tables)

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints of MySQL and Android-based SQLite, I haven't seen many alternatives.  Oracle Mobile server comes close, but does not support MySQL, and it uses data comparison which can be more intensive with large datasets than data capture.  [Pervasync](http://www.pervasync.com) supports your databases as well as Android, but it's not open source like SymmetricDS.  Have you discussed with the [SymmetricDS](http://www.symmetricds.org/get-help) project or [JumpMind](http://www.jumpmind.com/contact/jumpmind) about what's lacking, because I'm sure they'd like to improve it.

Comment: Says one of the SymmetricDS developers ;-)
Actually seems like a great product - looking at using it myself.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said full disclosure, I work on the SymmetricDS project.  :)